# change colour scheme of specific elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a script that checks what month it is and attempts to change the background image and the navbar colours depending on the season.

i have the script successfully finding the month and changing the background, but i don't even know where to begin altering the navbar. i've tried getElementByClassName and attempting to directly point to the elements (though i don't even know how to do that really) and neither seems to work.

the css elements i'm trying to modify (all "backgroundColor") are:

```
ul
li a
li a:hover:not(.active)
```

and

```
.active
```

i'm really a beginner when it comes to coding (which explains why i built my navbar using an html list), especially javascript, and my readings on the document object model just leave me lost. any help is appreciated!

edit: upon request here is both the code in question i'm attempting to modify and the script trying to modify it

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="music.html">music</a></li>
    <li><a href="art.html">art</a></li>
    <li><a href="games.html">games</a></li>
    <li><a href="hobbies.html">other hobbies</a></li>
    <li><a class=active href="bio.html">bio</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">links</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a class=active href=#top>top</a></li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth();
var b = "";
var c1 = "";
var c2 = "";
var c3 = "";

if (m<=1 || m==11) {
    b = "webbgw.png";
    c1 = "#b5e0fe";
    c2 = "#a5dafe";
    c3 = "#88cefd";
}
else if (m>=2 && m<=4) {
    b = "webbgsp.png";
    c1 = "#ade8ad";
    c2 = "#9be49b";
    c3 = "#7adb7a";
}
else if (m>=5 && m<=7) {
    b = "webbgsm.png";
    c1 = "#ff90bd";
    c2 = "#ff72a8";
    c3 = "#ff9382";
}
else if (m>=8 && m<=10) {
    b = "webbga.png";
    c1 = "#ffb420";
    c2 = "#efa507";
    c3 = "#ca8802";
}
else {
    b = "webbgerr.png";
    c1 = "#b9b9b9";
    c2 = "#a9a9a9";
    c3 = "#8c8c8c";
}

document.body.background = b;
document.ul.style.backgroundColor = c1;
document.li.a.hover.not(active).backgroundColor = c2;
document.getElementByClassName("active").backgroundColor = c3;
```

like i said, i don't even know where to begin with pointing the script to what i want to change, so i'm basically 100% sure the last 3 functions are wrong. i just put in something that i understood and the editor didn't yell at me for writing.

Comment: Can you include the html code? This shouldn't be real tough to do so I think you'll get a good answer here. You may wish to include the js you've been trying as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to put as much code as possible in a CSS file, and just change one thing, like a CSS class in the `<body>` to reflect the season:

```
const season = 'winter'; // or whatever logic you have
document.querySelector('body').classList.add('season-' + season);
```

Now, in the CSS file, you can use that parent selector to add a color to all relevant ancestors:

```
.winter ul,
.winter li a,
.winter li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: silver;
}
```